# Reverse Fixed Points in Kalyna S-Boxes and Reverse Engineering the S-Boxes

Tags: cryptanalysis, s-boxes, kalyna

I was examining the S-Boxes of [the Kalyna Cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalyna_(cipher)) and found that 3 of the 4 S-boxes have reverse fixed points i.e S[x] = (255 - x).
Is this an exploitable weakness? I was not able to find any open literature on how these S-Boxes were generated except for:

> S-boxes for 'Kalyna' were selected from the set of randomly generated permutations 
>   (random sequences for generation were taken from hardware-based generator).

```
+-------------------------+------------+------------+----------+----------+
|                         |     π0     |     π1     |    π2    |    π3    |
+-------------------------+------------+------------+----------+----------+
| NonLinearity            |        104 |        104 |      104 |      104 |
| Differential Uniformity |          8 |          8 |        8 |        8 |
| Absolute Indicator      |         72 |         72 |       72 |       72 |
| Distance To SAC         |        456 |        496 |      508 |      512 |
| Algebraic Degree        |          7 |          7 |        7 |        7 |
| Fixed Points            |          0 |          0 |        0 |        0 |
| Reverse Fixed Points    |   2(45,152)|          0 |     1(46)|2(129,132)|
| SumOfSquaresIndicator   |     200320 |     199936 |   203008 |   206464 |
| SNRDPA                  | 10.1132412 |   7.658872 | 9.398253 | 9.208378 |
| Transparency            |   7.834804 | 7.81397057 | 7.820098 | 7.823284 |
+-------------------------+------------+------------+----------+----------+
```

I was able to observe the following:
 Kalyna S Box - Pi 1 (Non-Linearity : 104, Differential Uniformity: 8)

```
A8 , 43 , 5F , 06 , 6B , 75 , 6C , 59 , 71 , DF , 87 , 95 , 17 , F0 , D8 , 09 ,
6D , F3 , 1D , CB , C9 , 4D , 2C , AF , 79 , E0 , 97 , FD , 6F , 4B , 45 , 39 ,
3E , DD , A3 , 4F , B4 , B6 , 9A , 0E , 1F , BF , 15 , E1 , 49 , D2 , 93 , C6 ,
92 , 72 , 9E , 61 , D1 , 63 , FA , EE , F4 , 19 , D5 , AD , 58 , A4 , BB , A1 ,
DC , F2 , 83 , 37 , 42 , E4 , 7A , 32 , 9C , CC , AB , 4A , 8F , 6E , 04 , 27 ,
2E , E7 , E2 , 5A , 96 , 16 , 23 , 2B , C2 , 65 , 66 , 0F , BC , A9 , 47 , 41 ,
34 , 48 , FC , B7 , 6A , 88 , A5 , 53 , 86 , F9 , 5B , DB , 38 , 7B , C3 , 1E ,
22 , 33 , 24 , 28 , 36 , C7 , B2 , 3B , 8E , 77 , BA , F5 , 14 , 9F , 08 , 55 ,
9B , 4C , FE , 60 , 5C , DA , 18 , 46 , CD , 7D , 21 , B0 , 3F , 1B , 89 , FF ,
EB , 84 , 69 , 3A , 9D , D7 , D3 , 70 , 67 , 40 , B5 , DE , 5D , 30 , 91 , B1 ,
78 , 11 , 01 , E5 , 00 , 68 , 98 , A0 , C5 , 02 , A6 , 74 , 2D , 0B , A2 , 76 ,
B3 , BE , CE , BD , AE , E9 , 8A , 31 , 1C , EC , F1 , 99 , 94 , AA , F6 , 26 ,
2F , EF , E8 , 8C , 35 , 03 , D4 , 7F , FB , 05 , C1 , 5E , 90 , 20 , 3D , 82 ,
F7 , EA , 0A , 0D , 7E , F8 , 50 , 1A , C4 , 07 , 57 , B8 , 3C , 62 , E3 , C8 ,
AC , 52 , 64 , 10 , D0 , D9 , 13 , 0C , 12 , 29 , 51 , B9 , CF , D6 , 73 , 8D ,
81 , 54 , C0 , ED , 4E , 44 , A7 , 2A , 85 , 25 , E6 , CA , 7C , 8B , 56 , 80
```

After swapping 41 Elements given by ()

New S Box  (Non-Linearity : 112, Differential Uniformity: 4)

```
 A8 , 43 , 5F , 06 , 6B , 75 , 6C , 59 , 71 , DF , 87 ,(FC),(FB), F0 ,(68), 09 ,
 6D ,(18), 1D ,(85), C9 , 4D , 2C , AF , 79 , E0 , 97 , FD , 6F ,(A2),(77), 39 ,
(01), DD , A3 , 4F , B4 , B6 , 9A , 0E , 1F , BF , 15 , E1 , 49 ,(8D), 93 , C6 ,
 92 , 72 ,(C5), 61 , D1 , 63 , FA , EE , F4 , 19 , D5 , AD , 58 , A4 , BB , A1 ,
 DC , F2 , 83 , 37 , 42 ,(D2),(DB), 32 , 9C , CC , AB , 4A ,(8B), 6E , 04 , 27 ,
 2E , E7 ,(20), 5A , 96 , 16 , 23 , 2B , C2 , 65 , 66 , 0F , BC , A9 , 47 ,(86),
 34 , 48 ,(95), B7 , 6A , 88 , A5 , 53 ,(41), F9 , 5B ,(7A), 38 , 7B ,(70), 1E ,
 22 , 33 , 24 , 28 , 36 , C7 , B2 , 3B , 8E ,(45), BA , F5 , 14 , 9F , 08 , 55 ,
(BE),(11), FE , 60 , 5C , DA ,(F3), 46 , CD , 7D ,(7F), B0 , 3F , 1B , 89 , FF ,
 EB , 84 , 69 , 3A , 9D , D7 , D3 ,(C3), 67 , 40 , B5 , DE , 5D , 30 , 91 , B1 ,
 78 ,(4C),(3E), E5 , 00 ,(D8), 98 , A0 ,(9E), 02 , A6 , 74 , 2D ,(1A),(4B), 76 ,
 B3 ,(9B), CE , BD , AE , E9 , 8A , 31 , 1C , EC , F1 , 99 , 94 , AA , F6 , 26 ,
 2F , EF , E8 , 8C , 35 , 03 , D4 ,(21),(17), 05 , C1 , 5E , 90 ,(E2), 3D , 82 ,
 F7 , EA , 0A , 0D , 7E , F8 , 50 ,(0B), C4 , 07 ,(B8),(57), 3C , 62 , E3 , C8 ,
 AC , 52 , 64 , 10 , D0 , D9 , 13 , 0C , 12 , 29 , 51 , B9 , CF , D6 , 73 ,(E4),
 81 , 54 , C0 , ED , 4E , 44 , A7 , 2A ,(CB), 25 , E6 , CA , 7C ,(8F), 56 , 80
```

Is it possible that this S-box was generated by randomly swapping elements from an initial S-box that was made the same way as an AES S-box?

Comment: `S[x] = 255 - S[x]` doesn't make any sense; perhaps you mean `S[x] = 255 - x` ?

Comment: @poncho. yes you are correct. its a typo

Comment: [The Kuznyechik s-box was claimed to be selected from random too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuznyechik#cite_note-6), [but has been reverse engineered.](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/071.pdf). Granted that's a different cipher, but the claim of generating an s-box randomly would appear to deserve scrutiny, especially in light of your observation of it appearing to be a modification of the AES s-box. Also, I would think S[x] = 255 - x admits a simple algebraic description for the points in question; I have no idea if that is exploitable, unfortunately. Wish I had more then +1 to give...

Comment: how many reverse fixed points did they have?

Comment: How did you find the algebraic properties (non-linearity etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find Parent S-Boxes For other Kalyna S-Boxes (using a C# program i created for the same).

Parent S-Box For π1

```
 CE , BB ,{a2}, 92 ,{8d}, CB , 13 , C1 , E9 , 3A , D6 , B2 , D2 , 90 , 17 ,{65},
 42 , 15 , 56 ,{25},{f8},{c9}, 88 , 43 , C5 , 5C , 36 , BA , F5 , 57 , 67 ,{ea},
 31 , F6 , 64 , 58 , 9E , F4 , 22 , AA , 75 , 0F , 02 , B1 ,{cc}, 6D , 73 , 4D ,
 7C , 26 , 2E ,{ca}, 08 , 5D ,{f7}, 3E , 9F , 14 , C8 , AE ,{72}, 10 , D8 ,{96},
{c4}, 6B , 69 ,{63}, BD , 33 , AB , FA , D1 , 9B , 68 , 4E , 16 , 95 , 91 , EE ,
 4C ,{f3}, 8E , 5B ,{df}, 3C , 19 , A1 , 81 , 49 ,{80}, D9 , 6F , 37 , 60 ,{44},
 E7 , 2B , 48 , FD ,{bc}, 45 , FC , 41 , 12 , 0D , 79 , E5 , 89 , 8C , E3 , 20 ,
{ff}, DC , B7 , 6C , 4A , B5 , 3F , 97 , D4 ,{28}, 2D , 06 ,{98}, A5 , 83 , 5F ,
 2A , DA ,{1c}, 00 , 7E ,{eb}, 55 , BF , 11 , D5 , 9C , CF , 0E , 0A , 3D , 51 ,
 7D , 93 , 1B , FE ,{1a}, 47 ,{32}, 86 , 0B , 8F , 9D , 6A , 07 , B9 ,{23},{a4},
 18 ,{09}, 71 , 4B , EF , 3B , 70 , A0 , E4 ,{1e},{30}, C3 , A9 , E6 , 78 , F9 ,
 8B , 46 ,{7b},{40}, 38 , E1 , B8 ,{62}, E0 , 0C ,{b0}, 76 , 1D ,{b4}, 24 , 05 ,
 F1 , 6E , 94 ,{a8}, 9A , 84 , E8 , A3 , 4F , 77 , D3 , 85 , E2 , 52 , F2 , 82 ,
 50 , 7A , 2F , 74 , 53 , B3 ,{c0}, AF , 39 , 35 , DE , CD , 1F , 99 , AC , AD ,
{54}, 2C , DD , D0 , 87 , BE , 5E , A6 , EC , 04 , C6 , 03 , 34 , FB , DB , 59 ,
 B6 , C2 , 01 , F0 , 5A , ED , A7 , 66 , 21 , 7F , 8A , 27 , C7 ,{61}, 29 , D7 ,
```

Parent S-Box For π2

```
 93 , D9 , 9A , B5 ,{f6}, 22 , 45 , FC ,{46}, 6A , DF ,{64}, 9F , DC , 51 , 59 ,
 4A , 17 , 2B , C2 , 94 , F4 , BB , A3 , 62 , E4 , 71 , D4 , CD , 70 , 16 , E1 ,
 49 , 3C , C0 ,{b6}, 5C , 9B , AD , 85 , 53 , A1 , 7A , C8 , 2D , E0 , D1 , 72 ,
{7f}, 2C , C4 , E3 , 76 , 78 , B7 , B4 , 09 , 3B , 0E , 41 , 4C , DE , B2 , 90 ,
 25 , A5 , D7 ,{4e}, 11 , 00 , C3 , 2E , 92 , EF ,{ee}, 12 , 9D , 7D ,{e9}, 35 ,
 10 , D5 , 4F , 9E , 4D , A9 ,{b8}, C6 , D0 , 7B , 18 , 97 , D3 , 36 ,{2a},{c1},
 56 , 81 , 8F , 77 , CC , 9C , B9 , E2 , AC ,{55}, 2F , 15 ,{05}, 7C ,{61}, 38 ,
 1E , 0B ,{a4}, D6 , 14 ,{43}, 6C , 7E , 66 , FD , B1 , E5 , 60 , AF , 5E , 33 ,
 87 , C9 , F0 , 5D , 6D , 3F , 88 , 8D , C7 , F7 , 1D ,{cb},{26}, ED , 80 , 29 ,
 27 , CF , 99 ,{73}, 50 , 0F , 37 , 24 , 28 ,{e8}, 95 , D2 ,{23}, 5B , 40 , 83 ,
 B3 , 69 , 57 , 1F , 07 , 1C , 8A , BC , 20 ,{ba}, CE , 8E , AB ,{03}, 31 , A2 ,
{a8}, F9 , CA , 3A , 1A , FB , 0D ,{84}, FE , FA , F2 , 6F , BD , 96 , DD ,{6e},
 52 ,{d8}, 08 , F3 , AE , BE , 19 , 89 , 32 ,{ec}, B0 , EA , 4B ,{02},{48}, 82 ,
 6B , F5 , 79 , BF , 01 ,{75},{5f}, 63 , 1B ,{3e}, 3D , 68 ,{e6}, 65 ,{30}, 91 ,
{98}, FF , 13 , 58 , F1 , 47 , 0A ,{a6}, C5 , A7 , E7 ,{da}, 5A , 06 ,{eb}, 44 ,
 42 , 04 , A0 , DB , 39 , 86 , 54 , AA , 8C , 34 , 21 , 8B , F8 , 0C , 74 , 67 ,
```

Parent S-Box For π3

```
 {2d}, 8D , CA , 4D , 73 , 4B , 4E , 2A , D4 , 52 , 26 , B3 , 54 , 1E , 19 , 1F ,
 22 , 03 , 46 , 3D ,{68}, 4A , 53 , 83 , 13 , 8A , B7 , D5 , 25 , 79 , F5 ,{23},
 58 , 2F , 0D , 02 , ED , 51 , 9E , 11 , F2 , 3E , 55 , 5E , D1 , 16 , 3C , 66 ,
 70 ,{b5}, F3 , 45 , 40 , CC , E8 , 94 , 56 , 08 ,{8b}, 1A , 3A , D2 , E1 , DF ,
{5d}, 38 , 6E , 0E , E5 , F4 , F9 , 86 , E9 ,{de}, D6 , 85 ,{05}, CF , 32 , 99 ,
 31 , 14 , AE , EE , C8 , 48 , D3 , 30 , A1 , 92 , 41 ,{cb},{15}, C4 , 2C , 71 ,
 72 , 44 ,{18}, FD , 37 , BE , 5F , AA , 9B , 88 , D8 , AB ,{dd}, 9C , FA , 60 ,
 EA , BC , 62 , 0C , 24 , A6 , A8 , EC , 67 , 20 , DB , 7C , 28 ,{89}, AC , 5B ,
{c6}, 7E , 10 , F1 , 7B , 8F , 63 , A0 ,{bd}, 9A , 43 ,{8c}, 21 ,{75}, 27 , 09 ,
{59}, 9F , B6 , D7 , 29 ,{0f}, EB , C0 , A4 ,{ce},{77}, 1D , FB , FF , C1 ,{c3},
 97 , 2E , F8 ,{2b}, F6 ,{bf}, 07 , 04 , 49 , 33 , E4 , D9 , B9 , D0 , 42 , C7 ,
 6C , 90 ,{4c}, 8E , 6F ,{96}, 01 , C5 , DA , 47 , 3F , CD , 69 , A2 , E2 , 7A ,
 A7 ,{34}, 93 ,{c2}, 0A , 06 , E6 ,{65},{50}, A3 , 1C , AF , 6A , 12 , 84 ,{7f},
 E7 , B0 , 82 , F7 , FE , 9D , 87 , 5C , 81 , 35 ,{4f},{e0}, A5 , FC , 80 , EF ,
{b1}, BB , 6B , 76 , BA , 5A , 7D , 78 , 0B , 95 , E3 , AD , 74 , 98 , 3B , 36 ,
 64 , 6D , DC , F0 ,{b2}, A9 ,{00}, 17 ,{39},{b4}, B8 , C9 , 57 , 1B ,{91}, 61 ,
```

So i think it is fair to conclude that these S-Boxes were created by swapping elements (to remove any linear redundancy) from S-Boxes generated using power mappings in Galois Field.

Answer (score 4):

If you take a look at the discussion at http://eprint.iacr.org/forum/read.php?16,947 
one of the authors of Kalyna, Oleksandr Kazymyrov, states that the S-boxes were generated randomly according to the paper [A Method For Generation Of High-Nonlinear S-Boxes Based On Gradient Descent](http://ia.cr/2013/578):

> The generation method of substitutions was described in [eprint.iacr.org]. All parameters were taken randomly, except $x^{-1}$.

Comment: Nice! Welcome to crypto, oink.

Comment: you might be right about choosing f(x) = x^-1, since the distribution of Coefficients of Linear Approximation Table and Difference Distribution table of the 4 Parent S-Boxes are same as that of AES S Box